# Remove subfigures from list of figures when using tabularray package

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, captions, subcaption, tabularray

I am using the code below to create a figure with multiple subfigures which looks like this:

[image]

However, when I make the list of figures it also includes entries for the subfigures, which I don't want. How do I remove these?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth} 

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\pagebreak

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c]},
        measure = vbox,
        vspan=even}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-a} \label{fig:a}}
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, 
                                     height=6.5cm]{example-image-b} \label{fig:b}}  \\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-c} \label{fig:c}}    
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Overall caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For testing I tried out what happens with `\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}` and then it became _much_ worse, which may be interesting for debugging. I have a slightly older version of `tabularray` though so maybe that behavior is different in the latest version.

Comment: Hey @beh99. I tested your code on my end, and it worked fine (NO subtitle).  Could you double-check it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MattD626 I double-checked and was still getting the same problem, maybe this is a `tabularray` version problem? That said, I think I have now fixed the problem (see my answer)

Comment: The subfig package creates lof entries for subfloats, but doesn't display them.  The subcaption package doesn't even create them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I seemed to have fixed this by just including
`\newcounter{lofdepth}\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}`
in the preamble, inspired by some code from the `tocloft` package. I'm not completely sure why this works, but it seems to do the job!

This also doesn't seem to interfere when making other figures with subfigures using the `subcaption` package, as I have shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth} 

\newcounter{lofdepth}\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\pagebreak

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c]},
        measure = vbox,
        vspan=even}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-a} \label{fig:a}}
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, 
                                     height=6.5cm]{example-image-b} \label{fig:b}}  \\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-c} \label{fig:c}}    
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Overall caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

% Test figure using subcaption package

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:normal_subfig_a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:normal_subfig_b}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Normal subfigures}
\label{fig:normal_subfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]